# Is there a portable version of Spybot Search & Destroy?

Tags: portable, spybot-sd

I'm trying to make everything portable, as my office IT has cracked down on native app installation. One of my favorites (and a good CYA app in this case) is Spybot. All I can find are [directions](http://portableapps.com/node/710) on how to alter the installation to make it portable. Is there a single download out there that would put the app right onto my USB drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of Jared is slightly outdated.

A portable version is available on [portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/security/spybot_portable) or [portablefreeware.com](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=2047) since may 2011.
Both are well known and accepted sources for portable applications.

Comment: Yes thats right, i've had it on my usb stick for some months now.